# How to show error if name does not exist in json file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have stuck how to show error if name is not exist in json file. I have tried if(searchField != value.name.search(expression)) and if(searchField != value.name) but its not working.Here is my code what I have tried. Please help. Thanks

js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropbox').css('border', 'none');
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  });
  $('#search').keyup(function() {
    $('#searchResult').html('');
    $('#state').val('');
    var searchField = $('#search').val().trim();
    var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    console.log(expression);
    $.getJSON('result.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        if (value.name.search(expression) != -1) {
          $('.dropbox').css('border', '1px solid #EBEDF8');
          $('#searchResult').append('<ul><li><div class="img_c"><img src="' + value.imgURL + '" alt="Profile Pic"></div><div class="content-box"> ' + value.name + '|<span>' + value.city + ', ' + value.state + '</span></div></li></ul>');
        }
        if (searchField === '') {
          $('#searchResult').html('<div class="message">No matches found</div>');

        }
      });
    });
  });
  $('#searchResult').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
    $('.dropbox').css('border', 'none');
    $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
    $("#searchResult").html('');
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="dropbox">
    <div id="searchResult"></div>
</div>
```

result.json file

```
[
 {
     "id":1,
      "name":"John",
      "city":"London City",
      "state":"London",
      "imgURL":"images/pic.svg"

 },
 {
    "id":2,
     "name":"Mathew",
     "city":"New York City",
     "state":"NY",
     "imgURL":"images/pic.svg"

},
{
     "id":3,
      "name":"Jackson",
      "city":"Washington",
      "state":"DC",
      "imgURL":"images/pic.svg"

 }

]
```

Comment: Add your `result.json` & HTML code

Comment: Hard to help without knowing the data, just debug this like: `console.log(value.name.search)` and check yourself what might be wrong

Comment: @Rk003 I have updated my code..

Comment: @johnSmith I tried but not getting any clue.Please help to fix this.Thanks

Comment: `console.log("NAME: "+value.name+" REGEXP: "+expression+" RESULT:"+value.name.search(expression) )` you should find an error there, also you didnt tell what is not working or what happens, it always passes the test? Or it never passes ?

Comment: also it might be handy to use a throttle so you dont spam the result.json while typing

Comment: @johnSmith Can you please write this code for me? When I start typing if name is not available it should show some error for example. If I type John or Mathaw than it should be show error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```js
var data=[
 {
     "id":1,
      "name":"John",
      "city":"London City",
      "state":"London",
      "imgURL":"images/pic.svg"

 },
 {
    "id":2,
     "name":"Mathew",
     "city":"New York City",
     "state":"NY",
     "imgURL":"images/pic.svg"

},
{
     "id":3,
      "name":"Jackson",
      "city":"Washington",
      "state":"DC",
      "imgURL":"images/pic.svg"

 }

];
function a(){
  var searchField=$("input").val();
  if(searchField==''){$("#results").empty();return;}
  var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
  console.log(expression);
  $("#results").empty(). append ("<ul>");
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        if ((value.name).match(expression) != null) {
          $("#results").append('<li><div class="img_c"><img src="' + value.imgURL + '" alt="Profile Pic"></div><div class="content-box"> ' + value.name + '|<span>' + value.city + ', ' + value.state + '</span></div></li>');
          }else{ $("#results").append(''); $("#results").append("</ul>");}      
      });}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input onkeyup="a()">
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: I am using string but anyhow its not helping me to find out how to show error if name does not exist in json file.Can u please give me any hint.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To display an error if no result is matched, just use an else-clause

```
    if (value.name.search(expression) != -1) {
      $('.dropbox').css('border', '1px solid #EBEDF8');
      $('#searchResult').append('<ul><li><div class="img_c"><img src="' + value.imgURL + '" alt="Profile Pic"></div><div class="content-box"> ' + value.name + '|<span>' + value.city + ', ' + value.state + '</span></div></li></ul>');
    }else{
       // if no match append error-message
       $('#searchResult').append("<p>No results found </p>");
    }
```